# iTunes keeps pausing during video playback

Tags: video, itunes, music, osx-mountain-lion

I like to work and watch movies in iTunes at the same time. Recently, however, iTunes has just started to pause randomly during playback. It is not a freezing issue - it is like somebody hit the pause button. Sometimes it will pause about five seconds after I have hit the play button. It is driving me mad! I have not done anything to my system that could possibly cause this.

I am on OS X Mountain Lion. This problem started on iTunes 10, so I upgraded to iTunes 11. It is far worse on 11. I have resorted to watching stuff on Quicktime Player, but I have to search for the videos in the Finder before I can play them. This happens with all of my videos, music, podcasts, et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of people having trouble with this and i have heard of two solutions and both are fairly simple. First, If you have any sort of apple remote or something similar nearby in the room remove it. I dont know why but i have heard of cases of interference like that. Second, Apple products are designed to pause if the speakers are disconnected so check your speaker connections and make sure it isnt coming loose or getting bumped in any sort of way. Hope this helps!